# Make a 2D Object Fly with trace from 0,0 axis to current x & y position of object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity 3D

I am starting a game assignment for learning purpose. I have some doubts which I couldn't find on the internet may be because I was searching wrong.

Please see the images for reference
[Object moving on X axis with leaving traces on X axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nc2I9.png)
[Object moving on X axis with leaving traces on X axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFzcv.png)

I am able to fly the object in one direction easily, I don't know how should I draw the traces here as in the image, once the object leaves the ground.

Please suggest what can be done to achieve the required animation.

I tried adding Trace component, but it is not drawing the exact result as in the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [Trail](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TrailRenderer.html) component and play with it's settings